# gcloud app deploy with private docker images

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, app-engine-flexible

I have a project that has a Dockerfile inside and inside that Dockerfile is a base private image. When I run `gcloud app deploy` it will return an error with the below message

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for dean, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

I tried `docker login` before running `gcloud app deploy` but it did not work

Comment: did you make `docker login <your private repo>` ?

Comment: yes, before doing the `gcloud app deploy`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this rolling is to push the private image up to Google Container Registry.  The per-project registry is private (only available to folks who have access to your project).

Answer (score 0):

When you provide the docker file,a container is build from the cloud rather than locally. so your private base container will not be available while building.
The best way is to build the container locally,then push to docker hub or gcr repository.
They you can push the container in the repo by the command below

```
gcloud app deploy --image-url=[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]
```

check on the documentation for more info https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#pushing_an_image_to_a_registry