# Is it possible with Google App Engine to pull from a private docker registry?

Tags: google-app-engine

Deploying an application to Google App Engine using the 'Custom Runtimes Flexible Environment' option requires a `Dockerfile` to build the docker image Google-side. I want to specify an image from my private Docker registry in the `Dockerfile` `FROM` clause. However, I cannot find any documentation or see any obvious options explaining where I would specify credentials for a private registry, or invoke a `docker login`. Without this, `gcloud app deploy` fails, of course, attempting to pull the image Google-side.

For example:

```
$ gcloud app deploy
...
Beginning deployment of service
...
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/1 : FROM registry.gitlab.com/my/private/registry/image:latest
Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/my/private/registry/image/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden
```

The `Dockerfile` in this case would simply be:

```
FROM registry.gitlab.com/my/private/registry/image:latest
```

Does anyone out there know if this is possible with Google App Engine, and if so, how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

There is this Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319804/gcloud-app-deploy-with-private-docker-images) that already covers the topic and provides an answer.

In fact, if you upload your image to Google Container Registry, it will be private and you will be able to control who has access to GCR by using IAM permissions. After that you can use it in your App Engine deployments:
`gcloud app deploy --image-url $GCR_IMAGE_PATH`

Comment: I did a lot of searching before posting this and didn't see that post you've linked above so thanks for pointing that out. However, using the Google's own image registry, while it might be private, is not the answer I am looking for. I already have my images hosted privately.

Comment: Maybe you can try using Cloud Build. With Cloud Build you could build your own image and run `docker login` prior to pulling your private Dockerfile and then use it to generate a image you will be storing in the Container Registry. This image will be usable in either Google App Engine or Cloud Run. Again, it comes to using GCR but you will be accessing to your private image inside Cloud Build and not exposing it to GCR directly as in my previous answer.

Comment: OK thanks. I have since got in contact with Google support and they confirmed that what I'm wanting to do is not supported at this point in time. They also suggested the Cloud Build option, as you have, whereby it should be possible to perform a `docker login`. In any case, the certainty that this is not possible is what I was after, so I can move on to other solutions.